# Is this a Correct Proof of the Principle of Complete Induction for Natural Numbers in ZF?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

I have reviewed a number of previous posts on this subject without finding an answer to my own point of interest, which is a proof that is closely related to ZF axioms and doesn't pre-suppose results on arithmetic, ordering or cardinality (there are a number of proofs using induction on the size of sets [cardinality] or which look at numbers < n (order) or which simply list numbers 1,2, ..n and then say something about n+1 [order and arithmetic]). **Here is my attempt at a proof which excludes arithmetic, ordering or cardinality : I would appreciate feedback on its correctness.**

Summary of *natural numbers* and the *principle of mathematical induction* (PMI) in ZF: define the successor of a set *X* as $X^+ = X \cup$ {$X$}. Define *Z* as a successor set if $\emptyset \in Z$,  and $z \in Z \Rightarrow z^+ \in Z$. The *axiom of infinity* guarantees the existence of a successor set. Define $\omega$ as the minimal successor set and prove $\omega \subset$ every successor set. Define the natural numbers as the elements of $\omega$ and label them $0 = \emptyset; 1 = 0^+ = \, ${$0$}$; 2 = 1^+ = \,${$0, 1$}$, ...$. **PMI then says that if $S \subset \omega$ and if $\emptyset \in S$,  and $s \in S \Rightarrow s^+ \in S$, then $S = \omega$.** The proof is trivial: *S* is by definition a successor set and so $\omega \subset S$ and $S \subset \omega$ therefore $S = \omega$.

Statement of the *principle of complete induction for natural numbers* (PCI) in ZF. Without involving order, **PCI can be stated that if $\emptyset \ne S \subset \omega$  and if for $s \in \omega$, *s* $ \subset S \Rightarrow s \in S$, then $S = \omega$**. To see how this relates to a more common expression of PCI, note that the order relation on the naturals is defined by $x < s$ if $x \in s$. The elements of the set *s* are thus all the numbers less than s: so with the additional interpretation of order, PCI says that for a non-empty set *S*, if $x \in S \;\forall   \; x < s \Rightarrow s \in S$ then $S = \omega$.

**Proof: PMI $\Rightarrow$ PCI.** Let *S* be a non-empty subset of $\omega$ where for $s \in \omega$, *s* $ \subset S \Rightarrow s \in S$.

Note that $0 \in S$ because $0 (\in \omega) = \emptyset$ and $\emptyset \subset any set$ so $\emptyset (=0) \subset S \Rightarrow 0 \in S$

Let $T \subset S = ${$t \in S:t \subset S$}

$0 \in T$ because  $0 \in S$ and $ 0 \subset S$,

If $n (\in \omega)\in T$ then by the property of *T*  $(n \in S$ and $n$ $ \subset S )$ which $\Rightarrow n \cup $ {*n*} $\subset S$. (see ** below)

But $ n \cup $ {*n*} $ = n^+$, so $n^+$ $ \subset S$ and by  the property of *S*, $n^+$ $ \subset S \Rightarrow$   $n^+ \in S$

So by the specification of *T*, with $n^+ \in S$ and $n^+$ $ \subset S$ then $n^+ \in T$.

So, $0 \in T$ and if $n \in T$ then $n^+ \in T$, so by PMI $T = \omega$, and $\omega = T \subset S \ \subset \omega$ so $S = \omega$ ∎

**** What $ n \cup $ {*n*} is, and why $(n \in S$ and $n$ $ \subset S )$ $\Rightarrow  n \cup $ {*n*} is a subset of *S***. The nesting of sets can be confusing.  $ n \cup $ {*n*} is a set whose elements are the elements of *n*, and the set *n* itself. If $m \in  n \cup $ {*n*}, then either (a) *m* is an element of *n* i.e. $m \in n$,  or (b)  $m = n$ .  If (a) since  $n$ $ \subset S $ then $m \in n \subset S \Rightarrow m \in S$ or if (b), since $n \in S$ then $m = n \in S$.  So in either case $m \in  n \cup $ {*n*} $\Rightarrow m \in S$, which is exactly the definition that $ n \cup $ {*n*} is a subset of *S*.

Comment: @TomCollinge I haven't got time to go through your proof, but I have struggled with this notion using not ZFC, but my own set theory. If we assume the existence of a Dedekind infinite set (roughly equivalent to AoI in ZFC), you can prove the existence of a subset of that set that satisfies all of Peano's axioms including PMI. See my own formal proof at http://www.dcproof.com/ProofByInduction.html

Comment: $X ∪ Y ⊆ Z ↔ X ⊆ Z ∧ Y ⊆ Z$ and $x ∈ X ↔ \{ x \} ⊆ X$.

Comment: Right ! thanks ... Thanks also to @user143882

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is essentially correct (although, if you don't mind my saying, hard to read). Just one thing: it is not necessary to assume $S \ne \emptyset$ since, as you show, $0 \in S$ follows from $0 \subset S$.

It is also possible to prove PCI $\implies$ PMI in a similar way, relying on the fact that every nonzero natural number is the successor of a natural number.

Comment: Velcome to the site!

Comment: @Pierre B. Thanks for feedback. I hadn't picked up that $0 \in S$ automatically: amazing what a younger mind can see !