# prove weak induction implies strong induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

So trying to prove:

i) $[t(n_0)\wedge \forall_n[t(n)\rightarrow t(n+1)]\Rightarrow \forall_{n_0\le n}t(n)]$

$\Rightarrow$

ii) $[s(n_0)\wedge s(n_1)\wedge\cdots \wedge s(n_k)\wedge\forall_n[s(n-k)\wedge s(n-k+1)\wedge\cdots \wedge s(n-1)\wedge s(n)\rightarrow s(n+1)]\Rightarrow \forall_{n_0\le n}s(n)]$

$1.)$ Let function $t(n) = s(n)\wedge s(n+1)\wedge\cdots \wedge s(n+k-1)\wedge s(n+k)$

$2.)$ assume $s(n_0)\wedge s(n_1)\wedge\cdots \wedge s(n_k)$

$3.)$ $\therefore t(n_0)$ $\space\space\space\space 1)$ and $2)$

$4.)$ assume $\forall_n[s(n-k)\wedge s(n-k+1)\wedge\cdots \wedge s(n-1)\wedge s(n)\rightarrow s(n+1)]$

$5.)$ for sbac $q\in Z$, $s(q-k)\wedge s(q-k+1)\wedge\cdots \wedge s(q-1)\wedge s(q)\rightarrow s(q+1)$ $\space\space\space\space 4)$ and Rule of Universal Specification

$6.)$ $\therefore s(q)\wedge s(q+1)\wedge\cdots \wedge s(q+k-1)\wedge s(q+k)\rightarrow s(q+k+1)$ $\space\space\space\space5)$

$7.)$ $s(q)\wedge s(q+1)\wedge\cdots \wedge s(q+k-1)\wedge s(q+k)\rightarrow s(q)\wedge s(q+1)\wedge\cdots \wedge s(q+k-1)\wedge s(q+k)$

$8.)$ ($(a\rightarrow b\wedge a\rightarrow c)\Rightarrow a\rightarrow b\wedge c$ established via truth table - omitted)

$10.)$ $s(q)\wedge s(q+1)\wedge\cdots \wedge s(q+k-1)\wedge s(q+k)\rightarrow s(q)\wedge s(q+1)\wedge\cdots \wedge s(q+k-1)\wedge s(q+k)\wedge s(q+k+1)$ $\space\space\space\space 6),7),8)$, Rule of Conjunction

$11.)$ $\forall_n[s(n)\wedge s(n+1)\wedge\cdots \wedge s(n+k-1)\wedge s(n+k)\rightarrow s(n)\wedge s(n+1)\wedge\cdots \wedge s(n+k-1)\wedge s(n+k)\wedge s(n+k+1)]$ $\space\space\space\space 10)$ and Rule of Universal Generalization

$12.)$ $\forall_n[t(n)\rightarrow t(n+1)]$ $\space\space\space\space 1)$ and $11)$

$13.)$ $\forall_{n_0\le n}t(n)$ $\space\space\space\space 3)$ and $12)$ and i)*

$14.)$ $\therefore \forall_{n_0\le n}s(n)$ $\space\space\space\space 1)$ and $13)$

Comment: Don't you mean strong induction implies weak induction?

Comment: You can also [here](https://bspace.berkeley.edu/access/content/group/2fb5bd3e-8d09-40ee-a371-6cc033d854b9/ho1.pdf)

Comment: Find a ZFC answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798992/is-this-a-correct-proof-of-the-principle-of-complete-induction-for-natural-numbe

Comment: @Jack: Nope.  I know what you mean though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Strong Induction* :

> $(\forall x)((\forall z)(z < x \rightarrow P(z)) \rightarrow P(x)) \rightarrow (\forall x)P(x)$.

To prove it from *Induction* , we have to define $Q(x) := (\forall z)(z \le x \rightarrow P(z))$ and apply *Induction* to $Q(x)$.

---

See Elliott Mendelson, [Introduction to mathematical logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0412808307) (4ed - 1997), **PROPOSITION 3.9**, page 166 :

*Proof*

(A)

*(i)* $(\forall x)((\forall z)(z < x \rightarrow P(z)) \rightarrow P(x))$ --- assumed

*(ii)* $(\forall z)(z < 0 \rightarrow P(z)) \rightarrow P(0))$ --- from (i) by $\forall$-elim

*(iii)* $(\forall z)\lnot (z < 0)$ --- provable from axioms

*(iv)* $(\forall z)(z < 0 \rightarrow P(z))$ --- from *tautology* : $\lnot A \rightarrow (A \rightarrow B)$ and (iii) and $\forall$-intro

*(v)* $P(0)$ --- from (ii) and (iv) by *modus ponens*

*(vi)* $(\forall z)(z \le 0 \rightarrow P(z))$ --- from the fact that : for any natural number $k$ and any formula $\varphi$, $\varphi(0) \land \varphi(1) \land \ldots \land \varphi(k) \leftrightarrow (\forall x)(x \le k \rightarrow \varphi(x))$.

But (vi) is $Q(0)$; thus, from (i)-(vi) we have :

> $(\forall x)((\forall z)(z < x \rightarrow P(z)) \rightarrow P(x)) \vdash Q(0)$.

---

(B)

In the same way, we prove that from assumptions : $(\forall x)((\forall z)(z < x \rightarrow P(z)) \rightarrow P(x))$ and $Q(x)$, $Q(x')$ follows [where $x'$ is $S(x)$, the "successor" of $x$].

Thus, by *Deduction Theorem* :

> $(\forall x)((\forall z)(z < x \rightarrow P(z)) \rightarrow P(x)) \vdash (\forall x)(Q(x) \rightarrow Q(x'))$.

By (A), (B) and *Induction*, we obtain $(\forall x)((\forall z)(z < x \rightarrow P(z)) \rightarrow P(x)) \vdash (\forall x)Q(x)$, that is :

> $(\forall x)((\forall z)(z < x \rightarrow P(z)) \rightarrow P(x)) \vdash (\forall x)(\forall z)(z \le x \rightarrow P(z))$.

Hence, by rule $\forall$-elim twice , $(\forall x)((\forall z)(z < x \rightarrow P(z)) \rightarrow P(x)) \vdash (x \le x \rightarrow P(x))$.

But we have : $\vdash x \le x$.

Thus,  $(\forall x)((\forall z)(z < x \rightarrow P(z)) \rightarrow P(x)) \vdash P(x)$; by $\forall$-intro and the *Deduction theorem* :

> > $(\forall x)((\forall z)(z < x \rightarrow P(z)) \rightarrow P(x)) \vdash (\forall x)P(x)$.

Comment: (A)(iii)?  Proved it before?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\neg (z<0)$?  Is that just because we're only dealing with natural numbers?  Thanks.