# How to complete proof of strong induction from weak induction

Tags: logic, induction, proof-explanation

I am wanting a proof of strong induction from weak induction.  This has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/984910/prove-weak-induction-implies-strong-induction), and I can follow the proof except for how part B is obtained.   Assuming that:

$\forall x(\forall z(z < x \to P(z)) \to P(x))$

and

$\forall z(z \le x \to P(z))$ --- defined as "$Q(x)$"

are true, I need to derive $Q(s(x))$.  That is, $\forall z(z \le s(x) \to P(z))$, where $s$ is the successor function.

All I can achieve is the following:

1. $\forall x(\forall z(z < x \to P(z)) \to P(x))$  --Assume

   $\forall z(z \le x \to P(z))$  --Assume $Q(x)$

   ???

   ???

   $\forall z(z \le s(x) \to P(z))$

   $Q(s(x))$

   $Q(x) \to Q(s(x))$

   $\forall x(Q(x) \to Q(S(x)))$

   $\forall x(\forall z(z < x \to P(z)) \to P(x)) \vdash \forall x(Q(x) \to Q(S(x)))$

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It may be 3. $s(x)\iff[x+1]$ followed by 4. $∀x[∀z(z≤s(x)→P(z))→P(x)]$ .
Although this depends upon your definition of the successor function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to instantiate your proof's overall assumption on line 1 with $s(x)$ for $x$ (for part A, you had to instantiate $0$ for $x$, but for part B you instantiate $s(x)$).

I do this on line 3 (exactly where you got stuck):

$\def\fitch#1#2{\begin{array}{|l}#1 \\ \hline #2\end{array}}$

$\fitch{
1.  \forall x (\forall z (z < x \rightarrow P(z)) \rightarrow P(x)) \quad Assume}
{\fitch{
2. \forall z (z \le x \rightarrow P(z)) \quad Assume}{
3. \forall z (z < s(x) \rightarrow P(z)) \rightarrow P(s(x)) \quad \forall \ Elim \ 1\\
\fitch {
4. z < s(x) \quad Assume}{
5. z \le x \quad from \ 4\\
6. P(z) \quad from \ 2,5}\\
7. \forall z (z < s(x) \rightarrow P(z)) \quad \forall \ Intro \ 4-6\\
8. P(s(x)) \quad \rightarrow \ Elim \ 3,7\\
\fitch{
9. z \le s(x) \quad Assume}{
10. z < s(x) \lor z = x \quad \ from \ 9\\
\fitch{
11. z < s(x) \quad Assume
}{
12. P(z) \quad from \ 7,11}\\
\fitch{
13. z = s(x)}{
14. P(z) \quad = \ Elim \ 8,13}\\
15. P(z) \quad \lor \ Elim \ 10,11-12,13-14}\\
16. \forall z (z \le s(x) \rightarrow P(z)) \quad \forall \ Intro \ 9-15} \\}$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and also for introducing me to how to format Fitch style proofs, I had no idea this was possible...

Comment: @esotechnica You're welcome!  And yes, pass on the Fitch format ... I learned that from someone else.

Comment: @Bramz28 I think there is a typo  in line 2. The first $x$ should be a $z$.

Comment: @Dole Yes, good catch, thanks!