# Property for the natural numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

This question is inspired by another question I had, where I wanted to prove something about the natural numbers.

Often in analysis books I see some proofs, where they use the natural numbers, but it is not really proved why they can argue like they do with the natural numbers, and I never even thought it was a problem, because it seemed so reasonable. Here are two different cases I have seen, it is the first one I am wondering about:

1. We make a procedure where we look for something in a function that has the natural numbers as it domain. We start with 1, and if f(1) does not have the desired property we create an alement $a_1$, if f(2) does not have the property we want, we create an element $a_2$, and move on. **Then we conclude that either we will have a finite number of elements $a_1,a_2,..,a_n$, or we will get an infinite sequence $a_1,a_2,...$, where every natural number k, will occur as $a_k$.**
2. We have a set S with the natural numbers, and we know that there is an n in the natural numbers that has this property. We want to show that there is a smallest element in here that has this property, we start by 1, and if one does not have this property we go to 2, if 2 not, we go to 3 etc., **then we know that we will stop before n, or at n.**

I have seen some books that have made arguments  similar to these. Property 2 is the well ordering property, and is proved using induction. **But can property 1 also be proved with induction?**

Here is the example of the proof that uses property 1. It is from measure theory, and all the details are not important for this question, the only thing that is important for this question is why he can say what he says where I have marked in red:

[image]

Comment: Is it accurate to call this induction in the way you have described, since the n case does not imply the n + 1 case? It is valid but it not induction unless one case implies the next.

Comment: @theREALyumdub: It is induction in the form of an inductive construction.

Comment: Property (1) looks like it's essentially _omega-consistency_ in disguise; effectively it's saying that _either_ there is some specific $i$ for which $f(i)$ is true, or we have $\forall k\neg f(k)$.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're asking. Any set is either finite or infinite, right?

Comment: My understanding of the question is: "We start by writing down $a_1$. At each step we either write down $a_k$ (where $k$ is the smallest number not yet written) or we stop. Then prove that we either end up with a finite sequence $a_1,\dots,a_n$ or the infinite sequence $a_1,a_2,\dots$." Is that the right understanding?

Answer (score 1):

Your property 1 is effectively the [Recursion Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#The_recursion_theorem). It is often (sloppily) referred to as an "inductive procedure," which is to some extent reasonable, because we need the [Principle of Mathematical Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) (or, [equivalently](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/433020/28900), the well-ordering property of the natural numbers) to prove it.

The rough idea is that if we can start a procedure, and explicitly state (1) under what conditions the procedure must stop and (2) how specifically to proceed to the next step if said conditions aren't met in a given step, then either the process is well-defined, and proceeds for a (possibly finite) sequence of steps. (As user21820 [aptly points out](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/21820/user21820), we must do more than simply *state* the above. We must *prove* that we can start the procedure, and that we can continue so long as the conditions for stopping aren't met.)

Comment: This is not enough. Just because you can extend a sequence to any arbitrary finite length does not mean that you can obtain the infinite sequence! Moreover, depending on how you do it, you may need some kind of choice axiom. See for example http://math.stackexchange.com/a/717963/21820 for some details.

Comment: You are incorrect. Note the use of the word "deterministically." By this, I mean that there is a function $f$ such that, given some $a_n$ that does not meet the conditions for termination, we define $a_{n+1}:=f(a_n).$ This uses the Recursion Theorem, and no choice is required.

Comment: Okay sorry I misinterpreted your use of "deterministically" since you said "deterministically say" rather than "say ... how to proceed deterministically ...". The former might mean you "deterministically prove the ability to proceed". If you edit it I can change my vote.

Comment: Does that change in wording make it less ambiguous?

Comment: Thank you, by the way, for pointing out the ambiguity! I had not considered that interpretation.

Comment: Yup I think it's clearer now.